# How to organize data in a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like

```
     used_at  common users                     pair of websites
0       2014          1364                   avito.ru and e1.ru
1       2014          1364                   e1.ru and avito.ru
2       2014          1716                 avito.ru and drom.ru
3       2014          1716                 drom.ru and avito.ru
4       2014          1602                 avito.ru and auto.ru
5       2014          1602                 auto.ru and avito.ru
6       2014           299           avito.ru and avtomarket.ru
7       2014           299           avtomarket.ru and avito.ru
8       2014           579                   avito.ru and am.ru
9       2014           579                   am.ru and avito.ru
```

for the years `2014` and `2015` where all strings are duplicated. I need to print my data like

```
         used_at  common users                     pair of websites
0       2014          1364                   avito.ru and e1.ru
1       2015          1208                   avito.ru and e1.ru
2       2014          1716                   avito.ru and drom.ru
3       2015          897                    avito.ru and drom.ru
```

I want to delete duplicate strings and instead print each pair to first output `2014` and then `2015`.
I tried to do this:

```
all_common_users = df.groupby([df['used_at'].dt.year]).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index()

common_users = all_common_users.groupby(all_common_users.index / 2).first().sort_values('pair of websites')


# keep only 'interesting' columns
common_users = common_users[['pair of websites','used_at','common users']]
common_users.columns = ['pair of websites','year','common users']

df = common_users[common_users.groupby('pair of websites')['common users']].sort_values('pair of websites', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

But it prints incorrectly. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["used_at", "common users"])
   used_at  common users            pair of websites
0     2014          1364          avito.ru and e1.ru
2     2014          1716        avito.ru and drom.ru
4     2014          1602        avito.ru and auto.ru
6     2014           299  avito.ru and avtomarket.ru
8     2014           579          avito.ru and am.ru
```

with `subset`:

> column label or sequence of labels, optional Only consider certain
>   columns for identifying duplicates, by default use all of the columns

Comment: It delete duplicate strings. How can it sort by `pair of websites`. I try `sort_values('pair of websites', ascending=False).` but not all pairs were sorted. Some are out of order

Comment: It should work the way you did. Otherwise ask another question with what you have, you'd like and what you tried.

Comment: @user116873 if it answers the question, accept it, so others will know that it fixed your problem.